# Black desktop after login for specific user

Tags: windows-10, login, black-screen-of-death

After I am logging in with specific user into Windows 10, I am getting black screen. I can see mouse pointer. I can logout, reboot etc and invoke Task Manager with Ctrl-Alt-Del. I can't run any process with it. I can kill explorer, but can't restart it. If try to browse filesystem, it hangs. I can run another one anyway. I can switch to various panes, including performance tabs, but they are frozen -- they show some values, wich are never change.

Computer never recover itself.

I can normally log it with another user. I.e. disks are working, video is working, network is working, hardware is working.

I tried to

-- ran troubleshooting (from another user)

-- disabled App Readiness service

-- Set HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\MYPROFIEL\RefCount = 0

It's still black

What else can be done?

Comment: Good answers below and it's most likely a corrupt user profile. However, there's a chance that user account has some kind of utility or software installed that runs when they log in and is causing the problem.  Before taking the steps below, a quick test is to use the System Configuration utility (can be invoked by msconfig from start menu) and then do a diagnostic startup or manually disable all the non-MS Services (Services tab), reboot and login to that user account and confirm the issue is still present before following the answers below.

Answer (score 2):

The situation you describe is caused by a damaged profile and it needs to be rebuild.

Do note, rebuilding the profile will cause you to loose all settings you had, but they can be set to what you had before. Unless you use a microsoft account, this is unavoidable, although I do not recommend to switch to a Microsoft account just for this reason.

## How a profile is stored

A user profile has 2 locations where its data is stored. A collection of files in C:\Users\ and settings in the main registry hive.

## How to recreate a broken userprofile and create a new one

First, go to C:\Users and move the old user folder out of this location. I do not recommend renaming the folder, but actually moving it out to say... c:\temp. This essentially becomes a backup at this point for restoring files later.

Right-click the folder C:\temp<username> and select properties, then head to the Security tab and give `Everyone` `full access` permissions, and ensure that it sets it to all child folders. If during the propagation it somewhere fails, skip. This may happen somewhere down AppData\Roaming or AppAdata\Local but is usually not data we need to actually restore later.

Right-click the start menu button and choose System to access Settings->System->Info.

On the page on the right side, scroll down (or look at the right side if the window is big enough) and access Advanced system settings.

This opens a control panel -> System page.

Here, on the Advanced tab, you find a section in the middle saying User Profiles.

Click <kbd>Settings...</kbd>

In this window, you have the registry collection of users. Select the user that you have trouble with logging in and click <kbd>Delete</kbd>. Do note, this does not actually delete the user, only its link to C:\users\Username is deleted.

Now, log out from your current user, and log back in with the user that was previously damaged. Windows will now create a new userprofile for this user and log you in normally.

The only thing that you need to do now is move the files from C:\Temp<Username> back to your current user. I recommend skipping AppData\Roaming and AppData\Local and only copy specific folders from those location that you want to move back, such as browsers (Chrome, vivaldi, opera, firefox, etc) and Thunderbird. No need to do this for outlook though.

Once done, keep the backup in c:\temp<Username> for a month in case you find something missing and need to restore that too, and you can delete it afterwards if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

> Black desktop after login for specific user ...  I can normally log it
> with another user.

The Windows User profile for the problem user is broken. It is normally not possible to repair a damaged profile.

Log in with a User that has Administrative credentials. Go to USERS and the problem profile. Copy needed data from the damaged profile to c:\temp .  You may need to take ownership of the profile.

Once data has been backed up, delete the damaged user account (Users and Groups), back up the entire user profile to a USB drive or like media, delete the profile (Advanced System Settings, User Profiles).

Then make a new account for the user. Because you backed everything up, you can use the same account name.

Replacing a damaged profile works.

Comment: Althought the analysis is correct, the solution doesn't have to go this far. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'keen' insight @spaceman-spiff I used msconfig to set a diagnostic startup on my wife's laptop. The miscreant account started up with the usual desktop. Subsequent restarts using the msconfig ‘selective startup,’ and using the event viewer, the offending service appears to be WildTangentHelper. So, for now at least, the WildTagentHelper app has been removed, requiring some registry editting. To note though, there was a long delay on shutdown due to '\Microsoft\Window\Internation\Synchronizing ...(Language?)...' service termination. Also there were 79 critical events logged during the period when the account was misbehaving.
As part of the solution, this is likely the last straw for MSW as my wife has finally accepted moving to linux. All the apps she uses are available (office suite, mail client, browser, video, music, recipe stuff, ...) without the hassles.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1240623)

Comment: In the answer I provided the profile/account did not need to be deleted; the offending program was removed and the account desktop opened.